# How can I encourage the browser to cache the HTML5 <video> poster image?

Tags: html, html5-video, browser-cache

I have a web page with a series of videos embedded on the page:

```
<video controls preload="metadata" poster="/path/to/video1/poster-image-1.jpg">
<video controls preload="metadata" poster="/path/to/video2/poster-image-2.jpg">
<video controls preload="metadata" poster="/path/to/video3/poster-image-3.jpg">
```

After I added the videos, the page load slowed down quite a lot, so I set about trying to ascertain the bottleneck.

The *Network* tab on Firefox Developer Tools reveals that each of the `poster` images is returning **206 Partial Content** and the `poster` images are always being downloaded from the server, never from the local browser cache - and it's this that is slowing down the page by 2-3 seconds.

How can I ensure that the `<video>` `poster` images are retrieved from the local browser cache instead?

---

Is the only solution to have a series of invisible images elsewhere on the page, like this:

```
.preload {width: 1px; height: 1px; opacity: 0;}

<img class="preload" src="/path/to/video1/poster-image-1.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="preload" src="/path/to/video2/poster-image-2.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="preload" src="/path/to/video3/poster-image-3.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: Are the poster URL's full links (like `http://example.com/images/image.jpg`) or relative (like `images/image.png`)?

Comment: The file paths are _relative-to-root_ (like `/images/image.svg`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to cache the `poster` attribute images, so I tried removing all the `poster` attributes.

I then discovered that even in the absence of `poster`, the `preload="metadata"` attribute was still significantly slowing down the page load time.

So, ultimately, I replaced `preload="metadata"` with `preload="none"` and wrote a short script to add the `poster` attributes into the DOM asynchronously, several seconds after the page had finished loading:

```
function asyncVideo() {
    var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');

    for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        var posterSrc = videos[i].getElementsByTagName('source')[0].getAttribute('src');
        posterSrc = posterSrc.replace('.mp4', '.jpg');
        videos[i].poster = posterSrc;
    }
}

setTimeout(asyncVideo, 6000);
```